# How to Register New File Type Association with MP3

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, mp3

I am beginner with Android Studio. I have an MP3 file in my `res\raw` folder. When I `sync project with Gradle files`. I get the following dialog box:

[image]

How do I allow for MP3 files in my project?

I read this: [Register new file type in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799576/register-new-file-type-in-android), but I'm not building an MP3 player. My intention is for the user to have an MP3 player currently installed on their device.

I also tried navigating to `File -> Settings -> Plugins` and searching for an MP3 player for Android Studio.

Should I just select `Text files` and move on?

I do not need Android Studio to play MP3 files.

Comment: it happened with me but it was all about the name of the audio file. in my case was starting with Capital letters

Answer (score 57, accepted):

That window is just how you want Android studio to open the file so you can visualize/listen to the file. It does not affect how the file is handled by android at all.

Since Android Studio does not have a media player, I suggest you to select *Open matching files in associated application* 
That will launch your default music player and play that mp3.

Note: remember that all the files under res should ONLY contain lowercase letters, numbers and underscores. If you have your mp3 with the wrong name conditions will not compile.

Comment: Thanks for the lowercase note. I had more or less the same problem until I realized that AS didn't know what to do with the uppercase file. :)

Comment: Love the note about the uppercase letters, how come this is the first I heard it!!?

Answer (score 21):

I decided to select `Text files`. This was a bad idea since opening the file results in encoded garbage output to the screen.

With help from [this page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJMGL.png). I went back to `File -> Settings -> File Types -> Text files` and removed *.mp3 from the `Registered Patterns` by clicking the red minus sign.

See this image: 
[image]

After this I clicked `OK` and re-synced the project with gradle. When this screen popped up again. I selected `Open matching files in associated application`. Now I do not get this pop-up and the mp3 opens in Windows Media Player if I double-click it.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

1. Select File -> Settings -> File Types -> Files Opened In Associated Applications
2. Click on the **+** sign
3. Add "*.mp3"
4. (If you have previously incorrectly associated "*.mp3" with something else, then Android Studio warns you and allows you to delete the old association)
5. Click OK

[image: File->Settings->File Types->Files Opened In Associated Applications->*.mp3]

It does not matter how you want to use MP3 files in your project afterwards. Android Studio now knows how to open them in case you click on them.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be an answer, but hope it'd be helpful to know that on Linux Mint Rebecca (based on Ubuntu 14.04), the problem is not reproduced.

Answer (score 1):

Kindly check the naming convention used for the file.It should be all lower case in the res folder. This will  solve the problem.

If not select on "Open matching files in associated application".

Answer (score 0):

This is a common error. Check whether your file is named in **lower case --this is very important**. 
Save file in text file format as showing in android Studio. Eventhough the icon is in text file in the raw folder, U will be able to hear the music on emulator or plugged in device.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check mp3 or mp4 file name. If you choosed Upper case letter for this video, you need to refactor it's name.

- all the files under res/raw should only contain lowercase letters, numbers and underscores.

Answer (score 0):

1- If you [added the mp3 file to your raw folder](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-add-audio-files-to-android-app-in-android-studio/) and you're trying to access it but it won't let you [change the import](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33858810/4833705) from `import android.R` to `import yourPackageName.R`. Also make sure that whatever filename you created for the audio file is lower case and doesn't have any illegal characters in it.

2- Here is the 2023 version of [@pintergabo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57275482/4833705)

`Android Studio` > `Preferences` > `Editor` > `File Types`

In the middle pane under `Recognized Files Types` select `Files opened in associated applications`

In the right pane under `File name patterns` press the `+` then enter in the `Add Wildcard` window type in ***.mp3** (don't forget the asterisk) and then select `OK`

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I changed the ".mp3" to "m4a" of the music and it worked